# Adding generated random numbers?

Tags: javascript, loops, web, random

What I except from my code is to generate a random number and then it would generate another random number and then add it to the old generated random number and so on. Simply, every time I click on the button it will generate a random number and add it to the old generated random number.

```
function play() {
    let p1 = document.getElementById("demo1");
    let p2 = document.getElementById("demo2");

    rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    for (i = 0; i <= rnd; i++) {
    var d = rnd + rnd;
    p1.innerHTML = d;
                               }
}
```

This is the farthest point I've reached, and it only doubles the random generated number, so it is not useful at all for my goal.
I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the bare-bones:

```js
function addRandom(){
  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  result.innerHTML = Number(result.innerHTML) + rando(1, 10);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
<button onclick="addRandom();">Add random</button>
```

It uses [randojs](https://randojs.com) to simplify the randomness, so don't forget to source that in with the `script` tag if you  want to use this code. I don't know why, but I also made a styled version. Have fun with it if you want:

```js
function addRandom(){
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"), result = document.getElementById("result");
  var from = Number(inputs[0].value);
  var to = Number(inputs[1].value);
  result.innerHTML = Number(result.innerHTML) + rando(from, to);
}
```

```css
body{
  background:#333;
}

#card{
  width:400px;
  max-width:90%;
  margin:25px auto;
  background:#fff;
  color:#aaa;
  font-size:16px;
  font-family:Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-radius:3px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#result{
  background:#cc66ff;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  padding:20px;
  font-size:100px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

#inputs{
  padding:20px;
}

input{
  width:100%;
  padding:20px;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-size:20px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  border-radius:3px;
  color:#333;
}

button{
  width:100%;
  padding:20px;
  font-size:20px;
  border:2px solid #cc66ff;
  color:#cc66ff;
  cursor:pointer;
  background:transparent;
  border-radius:3px;
}

button:hover{
  background:rgba(204, 102, 255, .1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
<div id="card">
  <div id="result">0</div>
  <div id="inputs">
    From:
    <input type="number" value="1"/>
    To:
    <input type="number" value="10"/>
    <button onclick="addRandom();">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this suits your needs and if I have understood you correctly:

```
function play() {
    let p1 = document.getElementById("demo1");
    let p2 = document.getElementById("demo2");
    rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    alert("New value: " + rnd);
    oldValue = parseInt(p1.innerHTML);
    if (!oldValue){
        oldValue = 0;
    }
    var d = oldValue + rnd;
    p1.innerHTML = d;
}
```

Basically, no for is required. Just storing the old value and then sum the new value. Again, please let me know if I have misunderstood something or mark my answer as correct if it solved your problem ;)